# Ionic Push notification: How to handle onClick?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework, push-notification

**THE SITUATION:**

I am using [Ionic Push notifications](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-overview) in my app.

Everything is working fine.

When the user send a message, the notification will be fired through a cURL request, and it will arrive only if the receiver has the app off or in background.

I have just a problem handling the onClick callback.

Following the [documentation](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-usage) I have put the callback function in the onNotification parameter.

> "onNotification": This function will be called when your device
>   receives a notification, and provided with the notification object
>   received.

What I need to do, when the user click on the notification, is to redirect him to a certain page.

It is working.

**The problem is that when the app is in FOREGROUND, the user will be redirected to that page everytime a cURL request is made... regardless of the fact that the notification has been received (app off or background) or not (app foreground)...**

**THE CODE:**

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $location, $state) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    var push = new Ionic.Push({

        "debug": true,
        "onNotification": function(notification) 
        {
            $rootScope.get_my_account_data();
            $location.path('app/chat');
        },
        "onRegister": function(data) 
        {
            console.log(data.token);
        },

    });
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I manage to setup a callback function that will be called ONLY when the user actually click on the notification, and not when he is inside the app?

I have to do some tricks inside the onNotification or there is a possibility to setup a onClick callback?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**THE SOLUTION:**

Ok I managed it using the `AppStatus`.
By checking it, I will apply the redirecting only if the status of the app is `asleep` or `closed`.

`if (notification.app.asleep || notification.app.closed)`

**THE CODE:**

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({

    "debug": true,
    "onNotification": function(notification) 
    {
        $rootScope.get_my_account_data();

        if (notification.app.asleep || notification.app.closed) 
        {
            // the app was asleep or was closed, so do the redirect 
            $location.path('app/your_chat_page');
        }

    },
    "onRegister": function(data) 
    {
        console.log(data.token);
    },

    });
```

**EDIT:**

Now `ionic-platform-web-client` is deprecated. You should migrate to [Ionic Cloud](http://docs.ionic.io/migration.html).

With Ionic Cloud few things changes, so now the code will be slightly different:

```
$scope.$on('cloud:push:notification', function(event, data) 
{
    var msg = data.message;

    if (msg.app.asleep || msg.app.closed) 
    {
        // the app was asleep or was closed, so do the redirect 
        $location.path('app/your_chat_page');
    }
});
```

Comment: can you show me an example of push notification in in ionicframework v1 and using ionic cloud.

Comment: In my answer there are both examples. If you need more info these two are very good tutorial: https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/  (how to setup all the stuff) http://docs.ionic.io/services/push/ (all you need for notifications on cloud)

Comment: your first link , I think is for older version...now in their documentation they are using ionic cloud...

Comment: how do you catch the notification?....do i have to write this code in my controller or in run?

Comment: Yes is for v1. But how you register and abilitate your app to receive notification on Android and Ios will be the same. And there is explained very good step by step. Then with ionic cloud the code to setup and manage the notifications is slightly different. The main difference is that the code will be inside the controller instead of .run() making everything more manageable.

Comment: If you don't have already Ionic Cloud installed, probably the most easy thing to do is to stuck with the first tutorial. After it works properly then it just take 10 minutes to migrate to Ionic Cloud, with just few changes in the notification code

Comment: i have a doubt..that is GCM free to use?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I was already registered to Google Play so I didn't worry about.

Comment: sorry if I'm disturbing you but I need your help regarding this.Can I contact you to clear some doubts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123143/discussion-between-johnnyfittizio-and-talentedandrew).

Comment: Where you are managing `AppStatus`, it is foreground/sleep/killed. I mean you will have to manage application state locally, that can not be sent from server, right ?

Comment: **$scope.$on('cloud:push:notification')** only works when user click on push notification, if push notification arrived and you open app from menu. new push notification will not be encountered. or code you have put on that block will not execute. Have you any solution of this ??

Comment: You can handle it in your app code. It depends on what you need to achieve. If you only need a redirecting in the push code - then obviously is not needed if the user open the app from the menu. The user won't expect that behavior anyway. Inside the app you can show (for example) the warning for an unread message and will up to the user to read it. It depends really on your case.

Answer (score 1):

i am working with this method and it is working

1.first initialize the push

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
       senderID: "XXXXXXXXX"
    },
    browser: {
        pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: true,
        sound: 'true'
    },
    windows: {}
});
```

2.`push.on('notification', function(data) {`
use this for the requested pushes and handle them like

```
if (data.additionalData.link_url.indexOf('http')>-1){
$state.go('x',{x:x});
}
```

Comment: So basically you are managed that inside the onNotification. But in this case that will always apply, both foreground and background right? I would need only in background.